# php form is not submitting in mailbox

Tags: php, forms, post, submission

This is the code for my form

```
 <form name="contactform" method="post" action="sentfrommail.php">
  <h1 style="color: #000; font-size:18px; text-decoration:underline; text-align:left; padding-bottom:5px;"> Personal Details</h1>


   <table width="90%" border="0">
     <tr>
       <td width="40%"><label for="name"> <span class="colored">*</span>Mr./Ms./Mrs.</label></td>
       <td width="60%"><input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="40%"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><label for="name"><span class="colored">*</span>Designation:</label></td>
       <td><input  type="text" name="desg" maxlength="50" size="40%"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><label for="name"><span class="colored">*</span>Company Name:</label></td>
       <td><input  type="text" name="compname" maxlength="50" size="40%"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><label for="name"><span class="colored">*</span>Address:</label></td>
       <td> <textarea  name="address" maxlength="1000" cols="42" rows="2"></textarea></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><label for="name"><span class="colored">*</span>Email:</label></td>
       <td><input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="40%"></td>
     </tr>

   </table>



       <div class="center" style="padding-left:20%; padding-top:4%;">                     
       <button class="button2" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"><span>Send Message</span></button>
      </div>   
  </form>
```

The sentfrommail.php is given below

```
    <?php

$EmailFrom = "mymail@site.com";
$EmailTo = "editor@mysite.com";
$Subject = "New Enquiry";
$name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$desg = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['desg'])); 
$compname = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['compname'])); 
$address = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['address'])); 
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 



// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Designation: ";
$Body .= $desg;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Company Name: ";
$Body .= $compname;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Address: ";
$Body .= $address;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

The form is not submitting.
Its showing the 404 page not found error. What Am I doing wrong?

i also used this method

```
    <?PHP
/*
    Contact Form from HTML Form Guide
    This program is free software published under the
    terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License.
    See this page for more info:

*/
require_once("http://www.example.com/include/fgcontactform.php");

$formproc = new FGContactForm();


//1. Add your email address here.
//You can add more than one receipients.
$formproc->AddRecipient('editor@mysite.com'); //<<---Put your email address here


//2. For better security. Get a random tring from this link: 
// and put it here
$formproc->SetFormRandomKey('CnRrspl1FyEylUj');


if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($formproc->ProcessForm())
   {
        $formproc->RedirectToURL("thank-you.php");
   }
}

?>
```

and the fgcontactform.php includes phpmailer. still getting the page not found error
Thank You

Comment: try to comment this, if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Now its showing a complete blank page.

Comment: not 404?, then 'contactthanks.php' or 'error.htm' is the error, not?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón its redirecting me on this page `www.mysite.com/sentfrommail.php` n showing a blank page

Comment: Wahts the content of file "sentfrommail.php", could you can put  this :<?php echo "hola mundo !!";?>

Comment: but in other way, if you commented code bellow, why is redirecting???

Comment: Before Commenting the lines you told me, it was showing this error "The requested URL /error.htm was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: And if you are in local?, there is a mailler configuration?, look at this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón No i m not using local server. still getting the blank page.

Comment: but, now is sending emai?,

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón nope, still no emails in mailbox. i have also used this form in my other website. its working perfectly in that website. only this site is causing me this problem. i even tried another coding for this form still not working.

Comment: will be in spam, or blocked by server..., try to use phpMailler or any, Better than use mail native. Will offer more capatiblity for control it

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón i used above code which includes phpmailer also. but the form is still not submitting. The form is not even changing.

Comment: mmm, strange. Try send maiil without form first, and then apply send by form

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón tried that also still no use. can it be server's problem?

Comment: have you readen the error of phpmailler, will help to known what happens

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón i just tried the same form on different website. there its working properly. i m also getting mail. it seems that no form is working only in this site.

Comment: coould be then server, that blocked it, look at logs of mail

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón all logs seems fine. Still not getting the problem. Thanx for the help.

Comment: try to sen to another email?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Still not working. i changes the email address, but still not getting the msg.

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code. It executes perfectly. I got a 404 Not found because I did not have a page called contactthanks.php which you are redirecting to.

Here is a sample code to send an Email :

```
<?php
$error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
// Define $username and $password
$name=$_POST['name'];

$email=$_POST['email'];

$designation=$_POST['designation'];

$companyName=$_POST['companyName'];

$address=$_POST['address'];

sendEmail($email,$name,$company,$designation,$companyName,$address);
header( "Refresh:2; url=../index.php", true, 303);
mysqli_close($connection);

function sendEmail($email,$enquiryID,$name,$company,$sub) 
{
    $to = $email; // If you want the user to get the email then make no changes otherwise change this email to the Email ID you want to send an email to.

    $subject = 'Welcome to Your Application';

    $headers = "From: " . "Your Company Name<noreply@domain.com>" . "\r\n"; // Please make sure you have an active email id you add here instead of "noreply@domain.com" which has the MX records indexed to your hosting.
    // The idea is that you should be able to send an email from the hosting server via your domain.

    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


    $message = '
                    <b>Name : </b>'.$name.'<br>
                    <b> Company : </b>'.$company.'<br>
                    <b> Email : </b>'.$email.'<br>
                    <b> Address : </b>'.$address.'<br><br>
                    <b> Designation : </b'.$designation.' <br>
    ';
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}


?>
```

Comment: I tried your code. It's not showing me any error. But it's not sending any mail either. The code i have given is working on another site except this one. i also checked server logs n setting. they also seems fine.

Comment: Your server has to be configured to send outgoing email. I am assuming your domain's MX records have the servers outgoing entries. 
 If you are on Godaddy : https://in.godaddy.com/help/add-an-mx-record-19234

Comment: yes, it was configured as Remote Mail Exchanger ,  that was the problem. now its perfectly working.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of help!